# Prove $\phi : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Define $\phi : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow  \mathbb{C}$ by $\phi(a+bi) = a-bi$

Let $z=a+bi$ and $w=c+di$

$\phi(z)+\phi(w)=(a-bi)+(c-di)=(a+c)-(b+d)i =\phi(z+w)$

Not sure if this is correct proof of homomorphism under addition are there perhaps more steps?

Then

$\phi(z)\phi(w)=(a-bi)(c-di)=ac-adi-cbi-bd=(ac-bd)-(ad+cb)i=\phi(zw)$

Again it would seem by the pattern I find proving homomorphism that this is correct but it doesn't look correct to me.

For the kernel:

$z \in \ker\phi$, then $\phi(z)= 0$, then $a-bi = 0$ then $z\in$ ?

Now $\ker\phi\in z$, then ? I am attempting to use subset-subset argument.

Then $z\in\mathbb{C},\ \phi(a-bi)= a+bi$ thus onto?

Thus by Fundamental Homomorphism Thm, $\phi$ is an isomorphism

Comment: $\ker \phi \in z$ doesn't make any sense. You just want to show that $\ker \phi = 0$. If $\phi(a+bi) = a-bi = 0$, then $a=bi \implies a=b=0$.

Comment: @William Stagner Yes, But the rest looks fine.

Comment: It might be helpful to specify the algebraic structure of which $\phi$ is supposed to be an isomorphism (it is an isomorphism for many, but not all, structures on $\mathbb{C}$). From the identities you check, I suppose you mean to check that $\phi$ is a ring isomorphism.